# How can the motion of a ball bouncing between two rigid vertical walls be considered as an "oscillation"?

Tags: oscillators

For oscillations the acceleration and displacement should be in opposite directions. But for a ball bouncing aren't the acceleration and displacement in the same direction.so there is no restoring force as such!

Comment: The acceleration **is** in the opposite direction to the displacement. If the ball is bouncing off of the walls, then it will experience no acceleration (uniform motion) as it travels between the walls, then when it strikes one of the walls it will undergo an acceleration in the direction of the centre point between the walls and hence, it is indeed a restoring force, the different between this and simple harmonic motion is that the object experiences an intermediary period of constant velocity for a certain amount of time before the acceleration phase, but it is still an oscillation.

Comment: That said, the phrase "restoring force" is a little misleading in this context as the force doesn't extent all the way to the centre (as it would for a pendulum). Someone else will have to comment on the terminology here but the acceleration is certainly in the opposite direction to the displacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia:

> Oscillation is the repetitive variation, typically in time, of some
>   measure about a central value (often a point of equilibrium) or
>   between two or more different states.

So a graph of horizontal displacement of the ball against time would be triangular and symmetrical about the mid point between the walls.
An impulsive force acts to reverse the momentum of the ball when the ball hits the wall ie the force ion the ball due to the wall acts in a direction opposite to the direction of the motion of the ball just before the ball hits the wall.